# « Je veux quelque chose de simple »

Tags: pronoms, prépositions, verbes, noms, de

Please consider the following sentence: « Je veux quelque chose **de** simple »

I do not know why the preposition **de** follows the word *quelque chose* (or equivalently precedes the word *simple*). What grammar rule is at play here?

Answer (score 2):

It is a common construction built this way :

1. a pronoun
2. the preposition *de*
3. an adjective, past participle, comparative and a few other qualifiers

e.g. :

> *Je n'ai rien **de** cassé.*
>   *C'est quelqu'un **d**'intelligent.*
>   *Quoi **de** mieux qu'un bon repas.*
>   *Rien **de** neuf sous le soleil.*
>   *C'est tout ce qu'il y a **de** plus français.*

Answer (score 1):

It's a fixed form: "Réalité indéfinie mais qualifiée par une précision subséquente. **Quelque chose de + adj. inv.** Quelque chose de beau, de bon, de grand, de vrai, de vague, de bleu, de neuf, de nouveau, de fâcheux, de merveilleux.".

The definition means this : given an instance of this form, it specifies something that is not defined but that has one characteristic, that characteristic being embodied by the adjective ; therefore from the context you might more often than not understand what that something is.

If the person's at a dressmaker and you hear someone saying "Je voudrais quelque chose de simple." you know the person wants a dress that is simple ; there is nothing to that, really, it's the same in English ; the only difference is that in English there is no preposition used in the corresponding form (example: I'd like something simple on this table, maybe a mere flowerpot with pansies in it.)